# AWS EC2 - File Sharing slow between VM's

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have two Windows EC2 VM's running in AWS.
Both VM's are on the same VPC and subnet and are m5.large.
Transfer disks volume_types are st1.
Task manager indicates throughput peaking at 11Mbps, but it looks like averaging closer to 3Mbps. This seems slow.

How can I speed file transfers on this network.

Answer (score 2):

The `m5.large` is listed as **EBS Optimized**, so it shouldn't be a problem with access between the instance and the disk.

The `m5.large` is listed as having **Up to 10 Gigabit** networking performance, which seems pretty good. You could try temporarily stopping the instance and making it a larger instance type (eg `m5.xlarge`) then starting it again to see whether this improves network throughput.

Worst case, you could **mount both disks on the same EC2 instance** and copy the files across, which would avoid network latency. (Or, if you can't stop and detach the disk, then instead make a snapshot of the source disk, create a new disk from the snapshot and mount it on the instance with the destination disk.)

People sometimes forget how big data can be. You don't state how much data you are wanting to copy, but as an example 1 TB of data takes a long time to copy regardless of how it is done!

Answer (score 1):

You can also try [AWS FSx for Windows](https://aws.amazon.com/fsx/windows/), but it requires a directory (AD or AWS Directory); so it may be overkill if you don't have one already